# AlarmMananger does not appear to execute - why?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have the following code to trigger an alarm, which when it fires is meant to launch another activity that is basically a nap alarm. After much searching through Google and SO, I am at a loss. I believe I have the correct setup for the `AlarmManager`, but the `Activity` that it is supposed to launch never gets launched.

By the way, eventually I want to use the `napTime` variable to set the time at which the `AlarmManager` will fire, but for testing purposes I am just trying to get it to fire  right way.

Here is the code to set the nap. The `Log.e("Nap time", "" + napTime);` line always shows the correct number that was selected for the napTime, so I know that the method is executing.

```
private void setNap(int napTime) {
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);       
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NapAlarm.class);
//      i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, 0);     
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), pi);

        Log.e("Nap time", "" + napTime);

        TextView nap = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nap);
        nap.setText("nap set");
    }
```

And the code for the activity that is launched:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class NapAlarm extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alarm_layout);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);

        Button dButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dismissButton);
        dButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button sButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.snoozeButton);
        sButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {

                    Log.e("Got this far", "In the alarm");

                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.alarm);
                    mp.start();
                    mp.setLooping(true);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.dismissButton:
            mp.stop();
            this.finish();
            break;

        case R.id.snoozeButton:
            Button sButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.snoozeButton);
            sButton.setText("I'm sorry, this app currently does not support snoozing, you must wake up.");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If I run the second piece of code by itself, it works and the sound plays, etc. But if I run it from within the larger project from which the `AlarmMananger` is supposed to create an alarm to trigger it, it never happens.

Is there something that I am overlooking?

Comment: Try getBroadcast() method instead of getActivity, `PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Activity.this, 0, intent, 0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your NapTime activity should be extending a BroadCast Receiver like this..

```
public class NapAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
//Here do your naptime code.

//YOu could actually have your NapTime class launch from this reciever if you want.
}

}
```

Make sure you register your reciever like this..

```
<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="NapAlarm"></receiver>
```

Refer here for more info

[Alarm Manager tutorial](http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129)

Comment: Is there any particular reason why getActivity() doesn't work? Is it a bug or just not intended to be used as I've used it?

Comment: Inside the Broadcast Reciever? You have to use Context context.

Comment: No, the way I have it currently implemented, why can I not use 

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, 0);

Why do you suggest something completely different when Android provides a mechanism to launch an activity with a PendingIntent? I'm just curious how to use the getActivity() method - or why I can't.

Comment: As was suggested, I implemented a BroadcastReceiver to launch the NapAlarm class, and it worked perfectly. I still don't understand why getActivity() didn't work though...